# Getting a AADSTS700016 error during Microsoft WSFed application sign in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adfs, ws-federation

I'm trying to use Azure AD as a standin for production level ADFS systems during development of an application.  Up until today, everything worked fine.  I don't know what I touched to break everything, but now I'm getting the following error:

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'https://foo.bar.localhost:44300/' was not found in the directory '[[GUID]]'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I don't know what's changed, or why this worked last week and not today.  I've been trying to change any number of settings - even deleted the app and re-created it, and nothing seems to help.  Most of the other articles online keep referring to old versions of the Azure portal, so the clicks/links/menus that they are referring to no longer apply.  There's a little popup on my sign in screen that says that I can enable "Advanced Diagnostics", but I don't know where those results show up so that I can see it.

Some things that I've checked:
- Under "App Registrations", the Endpoints for "Federation metadata document" and "WS-Federation sign-on endpoint" match what my application is using (so I'm going to the right place).
- When I click my application, under "Authentication", the Redirect URIs contains "https://foo.bar.localhost:44300/".  I've tried with or without the trailing slash (and, sometimes, both).

Those are the biggest two places that other articles imply there may be an issue.  Does anyone have any other ideas?  Are there specific user-level things that I should be doing?  Has something changed (very recently) that would be affecting my ability to use this feature?  How are Enterprise Applications related (they're a Premium feature, and my Subscription is not)?  I need to get my log-ins working again so that I can get my development process back underway.  Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get an access token for the App ID :  'https://foo.bar.localhost:44300/' which doesn't look like the correct app ID. 

Are you sure the clientID in your request for an access token is correct?

Comment: @FrankHuMSFT I'm not sure where to find the clientID.  It's not listed in the URL.   We've been using this mechanism for years now, and the application in question worked last week.  We've also verified other Azure Apps (in a different subscription) and they still work as well.  Any other ideas? https://login.microsoftonline.com/[[GUID]]/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://foo.bar.localhost:44300/&wctx=rm=0&id=passive&ru=%2f&wct=2019-06-12T11:50:56Z

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the right setting.  Turns out, many of my old applications were created when I was a "personal" user.  I've since become a domain/work user, and it puts some things in place differently than before.  In this case, I had to change the Application ID URI listed under "Expose an API" for my application.  Setting this (where it wasn't set to anything before) allowed my application to be found and my login to succeed.